# Can excess salt in a cured gammon joint be removed after it has been roasted?

Tags: salt, roast, gammon

[image: Oven Cooked Gammon Joint]It's my first time of cooking cured gammon joint and I wasn't aware of how salty it is until after roasting it in the oven.

I need to know if the excess salt can be still be removed even after it has been roasted in the oven.

1. If it can, what is the best way to remove it?
2. Will it still be ok to eat after excess salt being removed after it has been roasted?

Comment: Please provide an image of your roasted gammon.

Comment: Image as requested.

Comment: Make a mental note to not buy gammon anymore if it is too salty for you. Gammon just is pretty salty.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to remove salt is by soaking it in non-salted water for several hours before cooking it. Theoretically, you could do the same thing after cooking but I would advise against it. Soaking cooked meat in water will likely result in an unpleasant waterlogged texture. I would instead suggest serving it with sides and sauces that are deliberately undersalted (or even cooked completely without salt). That way, the meal as a whole will even out and not be too salty.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. It's too late for presoaking it. Would drying the cooked meat out after it has been soaked work?

Comment: Whilst I do kind of agree with this… what if everybody else eating it knows exactly how salty it's supposed to be & therefore wonders why everything else is saltless?

Comment: Too much salt is not good for you and if it's for other people,  you need to bear in mind allergies and each person's tolerances. This gammon is for only me but it's too salty for me and I don't want additional health issues to what I already have.